# integrating using trig substitution what happens to a limit on the original function?

Tags: calculus

I have been working through the use of trig substitutions inside of particle problems and have come across an exercise where the initial conditions seem to indicate no solution, but the solution shown ignores this. Is this a feature of trig substitutions, or is this just a convenient ignoring of the issue?

For clarification the problem has a particle at rest at $x=3$ where acceleration is given by:$$\ddot x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$$ which is undefined at the initial conditions.

Do we ignore this or do we need to consider this somehow?

Comment: The issue is not being ignored.  If you don't make a trig substitution, the velocity obtained by integrating the acceleration is finite.